# How long does a Ryanair payment stay pending?

Tags: bookings, ryanair

So I am violating one of my own rules and decided to fly with Ryanair for the first time. Apparently they are just as reluctant as I am:

[image]

> Your payment is pending - Ref: XXXXXX
>
> Don't worry, this is most likely because your payment is in a queue. To see the status of your payment you can  refresh  the page, or retrieve your booking with your reference number. Your booking will be confirmed when you receive an itinerary email.

Uh it's been like that for several hours. What now? When is this going to resolve? Google has nothing. Ryanair, obviously, even less.

Comment: Check your credit card issuer's website (logging into your account) to see if there is a hold on funds by Ryanair.  If so, all is well.  If not, you may just need to be slightly more patient; perhaps some transactions are verified by humans.

Comment: Did you book directly from their website? Never happened to me before.

Comment: No hold and yes this it's ryanair.com

Comment: It has been more than 12 hours now and no progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After multiple chat sessions with Ryanair (which were 100% useless) and the ordinary CC reps (who were utterly clueless) I turned to the fraud department who have quickly determined this is caused by making a typo in the expire date and that it will fail in 48 hours when I will need to rebook.

And not an hour after this phone call, about 20 hours since the booking it actually went through and I got the confirmation mail.